# HTML class visible when using inspect element, but can't be found with BS4 in Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to search for a particular class on a webpage; when I use inspect element, I can clearly see that the class exists. But when I use BeautifulSoup to find the class, eg

```
import bs4
import requests


url = r"https://twitter.com/TheSun/status/998755828931932160"
res = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
body = soup.find(class_ = "permalink-inner permalink-tweet-container"
```

Yet `body` is a `NoneType` object, which indicates that BS4 was unable to find a class by the name `permalink-inner permalink-tweet-container`. Anyone know why this is? If you go to the URL I provided, you can see that it is of a Tweet, and the class I am trying to access represents the "body" of the Tweet. This code works for some tweets, but seemingly randomly gives me `None` for `body`.

Comment: It may be because there aint any class with name `permalink-inner permalink-tweet-container` in the `soup`.

Comment: So why can I find that class using inspect element?

Comment: Can you see the class in response you got i.e. `soup` ?

Comment: Yes, `soup` is a `BeautifulSoup` object